# No access to bool in another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to create a shop system where you can buy a character to play with. When I buy a character in the Shop Scene, the bool value in the Inventory script is set to true. When I switch to the Level1 Scene, my character is not spawned. I suppose there is a bug in my GameManager script but I can not find it. Can you please help me? I do not know any more.

GameManager script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Joli;
    public GameObject Ninn;
    public GameObject Spaci;
    public GameObject Woodie;
    public GameObject Plumbt;


    public GameObject canvasObject;
    public Inventory myInventory;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myInventory = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Inventory>();

        if (myInventory.GetNinn() == true)
        {
            GameObject Ninnnew = Instantiate(Ninn, Ninn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            Ninnnew.transform.SetParent(canvasObject.transform, false);
        }

        if (myInventory.GetSpaci() == true)
        {
            GameObject Spacinew = Instantiate(Spaci, Spaci.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            Spacinew.transform.SetParent(canvasObject.transform, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently not enough information / code in your question, but when you change scene, your objects are destroyed by default, and new ones are isntantiated, effectively resetting any values that are set in them.

You need to prevent your Inventory or any object holding data you need to keep that it should not be destroyed when switching scenes, by using `DontDestroyOnLoad` for instance :

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick help I'll try it :)